# Mapping custom object to forms

Tags: c#, forms, dictionary

Can I map or automap an object to a Form and from Form to an object?
I have the following code:

```
// Class model
class Model1
{
    Property1;
    Property2;
    Property3;
    ...
}

// Form. I use this form to create and update data of Model1
public partial class FormModel1 : Form
{
    private Model1 model1;
    ...

    private void LoadData()
    {
        Property1Txt.Text = model1.Property1;
        Property2Txt.Text = model1.Property2;
        Property3Txt.Text = model1.Property3;
    }

    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        model1.Property1 = Property1Txt.Text;
        model1.Property2 = Property2Txt.Text;
        model1.Property3 = Property3Txt.Text;

        model1.Save(); 
    }
}
```

Note that I have simplified the example.
I want to set data from my model to the form and from form to my model dinamically.

How can I do this?

Comment: property1Txt.DataBindings.Add("Text", model1, "Property1");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement data bindings as follows

```
property1Txt.DataBindings.Add("Text", model1, "Property1");
```

To have this update the textbox when the property changes you also need to implement `inotifypropertychanged`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx.

then you will need to use

```
property1Txt.DataBindings.Add("Text", model1, "Property1", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged );
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do to achieve this is by using [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Another way, is by using the controls' [`DataBindings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings.aspx) property.

Take a look at these, take your time to understand the concepts and come back if you have any questions. In a new question, of course :)

Happy learning!